# Book where kids had the powers of manifesting things with their minds

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

In the beginning of the novel she is attacked in a park on her way home and these people come and save her. Later on she finds out her mom was kidnapped I think.

I specifically remember a part where she is  assigned a trainer and they have to go back to the hideaway where there are flat screen TVs and motorcycles (because these kids can manifest anything with their mind) and the trainer has her falling down a dirt endless hole and she is trying to get out so hard that her fingernails rip.

I think they can also shield themselves, e.g. making the house that they live in invisible.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange, Zoe! See [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999) for some help improving your question. For starters, **around when did you read it**?

Comment: Was it young adult? How old were the kids? Were there any **specific phrases** you remember?

Comment: I think I read it about 5 ish years ago- I wish I remembered any of the phrases but I dont - it was young adult - the kids where in highschool

Comment: The first couple of lines in this question make me think of "Running with the Demon' by Terry Brooks, it's been that long since I read it that I can't think if the rest of the plot matches